# Compare each line in a text file with text in Text/Combo box

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to compare each line of a text file with the text a user has typed in a Text or Combo Box for serial key check and blocking certain website. At the moment, the blocked content is inside the programs code itself.

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "website.com" Then
        WB.DocumentText = My.Settings.BlockedPage
        ComboBox1.Text = "Blocked"
    Else
        WB.Navigate(Me.ComboBox1.Text)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
    End If
```

I find this way to be annoying as it would increase the file size of the compiled executable and stop me from updating it without releasing a  whole new executable.

I have used this approach in another program, but I am sure the code I have used would compare it to the whole text file and not a line.

```
    Dim key As String
    key = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("key.txt")

    If TextBox1.Text = key Then
        'Do functions, such as create licence file

        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect key", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Key Check")

    End If
```

Would I just be able to modify that code to allow me to do what I want?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("website.com") Then
            WB.DocumentText = My.Settings.BlockedPage
            ComboBox1.Text = "Blocked"
        Else
            WB.Navigate(Me.ComboBox1.Text)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        End If
```

or

```
If ComboBox1.Text.Contains("website.com") Then
            WB.DocumentText = My.Settings.BlockedPage
            ComboBox1.Text = "Blocked"
        Else
            WB.Navigate(Me.ComboBox1.Text)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        End If
```

use .Equal() or .Contains(). Try using .contain() when your trying to compare with a .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing that:

```
   Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("File path")
    Dim text As String
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        text = lines(i).ToString
        If text = "Your serial here" Then
            MsgBox("Serial found")
        else
            Msgbox("Serial not found")

        End If
    Next
```

This code you can use for the webbrowser:

```
Dim lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "file path")
    Dim text As String
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        text = lines(i).ToString
        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.Contains(text) Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("")
        End If
    Next
```

The text in the textfile should be in the format of:

www.website.com

Comment: While I am not getting errors using it for the serial key (I am stopping un-authorised users from commenting on the software), it does not work for blocking the websites, for example if the website was badwebsite.com - that website would still show. Thanks for the serial key checking though.

Comment: No problem :), see updated text for the websites. Don't forget to set the question as awnser if it did work for you.

Comment: This also works, does it only need to be www.website.com in the text file to block http://www.website.com, http://website.com and so one or do I need www., http://, website.com and so on?

Comment: It checks the file for the string (text line) in the textfile. So if you use www.website.com in the text file, it checks if the url of the webbrowser1 has www.website.com in it.